# How-to Dynamic update a chart via socket.io and slide chart view as a sliding window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, socket.io

Could anyone help me to figure out what I am missing on showing only last X samples in the chart, please?

Looking at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) example and [this](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/how-to-make-dynamic-chart-using-data-from-mysql-with-node-js-t36229/) thread, I am developing a simple page which receives samples from server via socket.io and plots the last 10 samples.
However, it is not working and I am struggling to figure out what I am missing.

The server.js is a simple samples generator:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// On connection event.
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        // TODO (How-to) release connection (?)
    });

    var max = 100;  // Scale samples from 0 to 100.

    // Generate random samples.
    setInterval(function () {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
        socket.emit('chart_data', {
            x: x,
            y: y
        });
        console.info("emitted: [" + x + "," + y + "]");
    }, 2000); //update every sec.
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The html file include such script to handle the plot:

```
    $(function() {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
          global: {
              useUTC: false
          }
      });

      // Instantiate the chart object which plots the samples.
      var graph = new Highcharts.chart('graph_container', {
          chart: {
              type: 'spline',
              animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
              marginRight: 10,
              events: {
                  load: function () {
                      // set up the updating of the chart on each sample
                      var series = this.series[0];
                      socket.on('chart_data', function (sample) {
                          //add chart data to series
                          series.addPoint([sample.x, sample.y], true, false);
                      });
                  }
              }
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Live random data'
          },
          xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',
              tickPixelInterval: 150
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Value'
              },
              plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
              }]
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                  return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                      Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                      Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          exporting: {
              enabled: false
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'Random data',
              data: (function () {
                  // generate an array of random data
                  var data = [],
                      time = 0,
                      i;

                  socket.on('chart_data', function (sample) {
                      //add chart data to series
                      time = sample.x;
                      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 2) {
                          data.push({
                              x: time + i
                          });
                      }
                  });
                  return data;
              }())
          }]
      });

    });
```

I am brand new to node.js, but I believe that my mistake is pushing samples without y in "data.push". However, the plot is working, but without the "sliding window" of last X samples (e.g. 10).

Does anyone have a suggestion to let the "sliding window" work, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should emit two events - one with the data initialisation e.g. sample of 10 points, and the second - a point fetching in time interval.

You should not initialise the data in a way you do in the line `series.data = (function () ...` Instead move the initialisation on load event and use [series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData).

Your series should look like this:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Random data',
  data: []
}]
```

and the load event like this:

```
events: {
load: function () {
          var series = this.series[0];
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');


          socket.on('chart_data_init', function (sample) {
            series.setData(sample.data);
          });

          socket.on('chart_data', function (sample) {
              //add chart data to series
              series.addPoint([sample.x, sample.y], true, false);
          });
      }
  }
```

Then modify your server file, you need to add `chart_data_init` emission with some initialised data

```
var initData = (function () {
  var data = [], i = 0, time = new Date().getTime() - 2000 * 10;

  for (; i < 10; i++) {
    data.push({
      x: time + i * 2000,
      y: Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1)
    });
  }

  return data;
})();

socket.emit('chart_data_init', {
  data: initData
});
```

You have to have data sorted in ascending order - otherwise Highcharts will not render the data correctly.

#### Files

index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph_container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<script>
 // Instantiate the chart object which plots the samples.
 console.log
      var graph = new Highcharts.chart('graph_container', {
          chart: {
              type: 'spline',
              animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
              marginRight: 10,
              events: {
                  load: function () {
                      // set up the updating of the chart on each sample
                      var series = this.series[0];
                      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');


                      socket.on('chart_data_init', function (sample) {
                        series.setData(sample.data);
                      });

                      socket.on('chart_data', function (sample) {
                          //add chart data to series
                          series.addPoint([sample.x, sample.y], true, false);
                      });
                  }
              }
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Live random data'
          },
          xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',
              tickPixelInterval: 150
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Value'
              },
              plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
              }]
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                  return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                      Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                      Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          exporting: {
              enabled: false
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'Random data',
              data: []
          }]
      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        // TODO (How-to) release connection (?)
    });

    var max = 100;  // Scale samples from 0 to 100.

    var initData = (function () {
      var data = [], i = 0, time = new Date().getTime() - 2000 * 10;

      for (; i < 10; i++) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 2000,
          y: Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1)
        });
      }

      return data;
    })();

    socket.emit('chart_data_init', {
      data: initData
    });

    // Generate random samples.
    setInterval(function () {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);

        socket.emit('chart_data', {
            x: x,
            y: y
        });
        console.info("emitted: [" + x + "," + y + "]");
    }, 2000); //update every sec.
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000'); //jalankan server di port 3000
});
```

Comment: Thank you @morganfree !
Last but not the least, it is necessary to change:
"series.addPoint([sample.x, sample.y], true, false);" in html file to
"series.addPoint([sample.x, sample.y], true, true);". Otherwise, it wond slide the window ;-)

Comment: You are correct, I missed that ;). Otherwise, the point would not be shifted.

Comment: Don't worry, the most important thing is that now it works great! Thanks again ;)